# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'models.customers', but this dictionary requires a model item of

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass a variable into views. When I run the code and click the description, I get the following error:

`"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Vidly.Models.Customer', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel'."`

I have one controller this to be called: CustomersController
and 2 Models in the different folder where
Model RandomMovieViewModel in ViewModels folder, and
Model ViewModels in Models

```
public class CustomersController : Controller
    {

        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>()
                                {
                                    new Customer() { Id = 1, Name = "John Smith" },
                                    new Customer() { Id = 2, Name = "Mary Williams" }
                                };

        // GET: Customers
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            // bikin dummy data


            RandomMovieViewModel viewModel = new RandomMovieViewModel()
            {
                Customers = customers
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {

            var cst = customers.Where(s => s.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

            return View(cst);
        }
    }
```

ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel

```
public class RandomMovieViewModel
    {
        public Movie Movie { get; set; }
        public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
```

Models.Customer

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Index View

```
@model Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Customers</h2>


<table class="table">


@foreach (var customer in Model.Customers) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(@customer.Name, "Details", new { id = customer.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

My Details View

```
@model Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>RandomMovieViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Model.Name
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

How can I passing the dummy data created in Controller using Generic Collection List into the Details View from the Index View as you can see above, coz My Index view complete running as expected.

Comment: I found the answer... I changed @model Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel to ``@model Vidly.Models.Customer``in my details view then in _layouts.cshtml i deleted ``@model Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel``... and everthings fine... Why is it happend? if anyone know the reason, pls your advice to explain a simple answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear. Your Details view expects `RandomMovieViewModel`:

```
@model Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel
```

But you are passing it a Customer:

```
var cst = customers.Where(s => s.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
return View(cst);
```

So if the view really is operating on a `Customer` you need to change the model used in the Details view to:

```
@model Vidly.Models.Customer
```

Comment: when I checked in my _layouts.cshtml.. i deleted ``@model Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel`` and thats fixed the problems..

Comment: @JoeWilson yes that would also be a problem, but that code isn't in the question. You can't have the view and the layout bound to completely different models, unless you have something like the layout using a base model that the other models extend.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer... I changed

> @model Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel

to

> @model Vidly.Models.Customer

in my details view, then in _layouts.cshtml i deleted

> @model Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel

... and everthings fine... Why is it happend? if anyone know the reason, pls your advice to explain a simple answer. Thank you